# Format dataframe to Excel using openxlsx

Tags: r, dataframe, openxlsx

Any suggestion how can i deal with the two first rows? My data frame actually is just the second row (which has the title of the columns) to the bottom. But i don't have any idea how to add the first line

[image: example]

I've tried to pack two data frames:

```
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet2")
auxdata = tibble(`TEST` = rep('',nrow(base_original)))

writeData(wb, sheet = 3, x = auxdata)
writeData(wb, sheet = 3, x = df1)
```

but didn't work of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writeData` has a `startRow` (and `startCol`) argument to specify the region to write the data. Hence, you can set `startRow=2` to write your dataset. Then add the additional header line in the first row:

```
library(openxlsx)

fn <- tempfile(".xlsx")
df1 <- mtcars[, 1:2]

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet2")
writeData(wb, sheet = "sheet2", x = "TEST")
writeData(wb, sheet = "sheet2", x = df1, startRow = 2)
mergeCells(wb, sheet = "sheet2", cols = 1:2, rows = 1)

saveWorkbook(wb, fn)
```

[image]